# Автоматическое форматирование сложного кода с помощь clang-format

Tags: c++, форматирование, clang

Использую `clang-format` для автоматического форматирования кода и в большинстве случаев он справляется на ура, но есть код, который он форматирует не так как хотелось бы.

Кусок кода из примера к библиотеки ([файл на github](https://github.com/jarro2783/cxxopts/blob/master/src/example.cpp)):

```
int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    options.add_options()
      ("a,apple", "an apple", cxxopts::value<bool>(apple))
      ("b,bob", "Bob")
      ("f,file", "File", cxxopts::value<std::vector<std::string>>(), "FILE")
      ("i,input", "Input", cxxopts::value<std::string>())
      ("o,output", "Output file", cxxopts::value<std::string>()
          ->default_value("a.out")->implicit_value("b.def"), "BIN")
      ("positional",
        "Positional arguments: these are the arguments that are entered "
        "without an option", cxxopts::value<std::vector<std::string>>())
      ("long-description",
        "thisisareallylongwordthattakesupthewholelineandcannotbebrokenataspace")
      ("help", "Print help")
      ("int", "An integer", cxxopts::value<int>(), "N")
      ("option_that_is_too_long_for_the_help", "A very long option")
    ;
}
```

превращается в нечто не читаемое:

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
  options.add_options()("a,apple", "an apple",
                        cxxopts::value<bool>(apple))("b,bob", "Bob")(
      "f,file", "File", cxxopts::value<std::vector<std::string>>(),
      "FILE")("i,input", "Input", cxxopts::value<std::string>())(
      "o,output", "Output file",
      cxxopts::value<std::string>()->default_value("a.out")->implicit_value(
          "b.def"),
      "BIN")("positional",
             "Positional arguments: these are the arguments that are entered "
             "without an option",
             cxxopts::value<std::vector<std::string>>())(
      "long-description",
      "thisisareallylongwordthattakesupthewholelineandcannotbebrokenataspace")(
      "help", "Print help")("int", "An integer", cxxopts::value<int>(), "N")(
      "option_that_is_too_long_for_the_help", "A very long option");
}
```

`.clang-format`:

```
BasedOnStyle: LLVM
IndentWidth: 2
---
Language: Cpp
Standard: Cpp11
```

Можно ли это как-то исправить?

Comment: А вы уверены, что первый пример кода - это что-то читаемое? Лично я не понял, что этот код обозначает.

Comment: @VladfromMoscow, если знать, что происходит в коде, то для меня первый кусок кода более читаемый чем первый. И да, этот код не рабочий.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Оказалось все достаточно просто:

```
int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
  // clang-format off
  options.add_options()
    ("a,apple", "an apple", cxxopts::value<bool>(apple))
    ("b,bob", "Bob")
    ("f,file", "File", cxxopts::value<std::vector<std::string>>(), "FILE")
    ("i,input", "Input", cxxopts::value<std::string>())
    ("o,output", "Output file", cxxopts::value<std::string>()
        ->default_value("a.out")->implicit_value("b.def"), "BIN")
    ("positional",
      "Positional arguments: these are the arguments that are entered "
      "without an option", cxxopts::value<std::vector<std::string>>())
    ("long-description",
      "thisisareallylongwordthattakesupthewholelineandcannotbebrokenataspace")
    ("help", "Print help")
    ("int", "An integer", cxxopts::value<int>(), "N")
    ("option_that_is_too_long_for_the_help", "A very long option")
  ;
  // clang-format on
}
```

С помощью комментариев

```
// clang-format off
...
// clang-format on
```

можно отключить форматирование для нужного куска кода.